# TortoiseHg: cannot commit without an active bookmark

Tags: mercurial, commit, tortoisehg

- I created a new Folder
- I put some files in it
- I created a new Mercurial repository in this Folder
- I tried to commit all files using TortoiseHg

Until this Point I did this Scenario quite often.
But this time i get an error message `cannot commit without an active Bookmark`.

What does this error message mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I experimented with extensions in TortoiseHg.
I activated several of them not knowing what they exactly do...
In my case I had to disable the Extension **`bookflow`**
("*implements bookmark-based branching (EXPERIMENTAL)*).

Now the commit is working again as it should.
It's a pity that there is no explanation of these extensions in TortoiseHg :-(

Answer (score 1):

Something to note with bookflow is it requires you to have a bookmark. So with this being the case, you would have to disable it to make repo changes without an active bookmark.

A large part of what it was built for was to make bookmarks act more like a feature branch rather than a tag somewhat like in git.

https://backend.bolt80.com/hgdoc/ext-bookflow.html

Comment: The link is not working anymore.